# add variable as id name - flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, variables, dynamic, if-statement

I've got a little question answer app that I've created. Everything is working fine but now I'm trying to make the quiz more dynamic by loading and uploading different quizzes from a database.

I seem to have almost everything working fine but I've ran into a bit of a problem converting my answer check function from static to dynamic data.

Here's a bit of my code.

```
    if (b1.selected != true) {
        q1a.styleName = "incorrect";
        q1a.text = incorrect + b1.value;
        score = score -1;
   }
```

Like a said this seemed to work fine with static content just checking if the radio button was selected or not.

I need to replace - b1.selected with my database variable in this case its pertestq1a.

pertestq1a currently equals b1.

How can I add my variable to this if statement to be recognized as an element id?

Comment: show your loader code for the values from the database

Comment: how is b1 created? Maybe you should use a DataGroup to create all the questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the following:

```
this[pertestq1a].selected
```

Comment: You forgot the " => this["pertestq1a"].selected

Comment: @J_A_X No. `pertestq1a` is a variable the value of which can be `"b1"` which is a valid id in application.

Comment: oh, gotcha, didn't get that part.

Answer (score 0):

Hum I do not write AS3 code anymore but as far as I remember, and if I well understand your database structure (I guess you store the name as a sting) this could help you :

Let: pertestq1a = "b1" you can use the following to retrieve the corresponding display object.

```
getChildByName(pertestq1a)
```

So you can use "selected" method this way I guess:

```
getChildByName(pertestq1a).selected
```

Indeed, you need to specify a usable "instance name" on the object(s) to use it.

Documentation & examples: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildByName%28%29